# JavaScript - Push objects within object to global array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, xmlhttprequest

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript that allows for articles from another source to be loaded on another page using an XMLHTTPRequest.

Each article is a JavaScript object containing the link, image, summary etc.

Each request will retrieve 5 articles, but I only want to show 4 articles on each button click. Because of this, I want to push the articles (objects) to a global array.

Since I'm fairly new at using XMLHTTPRequests, I can't find how to do this.

Everything works except for:

```
var i;
          for (i = 0; i < newArticles.length; i++) {
            articles.push(newArticles[i]);
          }
```

newArticles is an object **containing** the 5 articles (objects) which I'm trying to push to the global array titled articles.

My code:

```
    var articles = [];

  document.getElementById("fc-blog-button-loadmore").addEventListener("click", receiveNewArticles);

  function receiveNewArticles() {
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "thelinktothepagewith5newarticles.json";
   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            var newObj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
          var newArticles = (newObj.blog.articles);
          console.log(newObj);
          console.log(newArticles);

          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < newArticles.length; i++) {
            articles.push(newArticles[i]);
          }

          console.log(articles);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send();
  }
```

**SOLVED**

After the helpful comments my code currently looks like this:

```
var articles = [];

  document.getElementById("fc-blog-button-loadmore").addEventListener("click", receiveNewArticles);

  function receiveNewArticles() {
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "http://freshcotton-dev.webshopapp.com/nl/blogs/blog/page2.html?format=json";
   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            var newObj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
          var newArticles = (newObj.blog.articles);
          console.log(newObj);
          console.log(newArticles);

          articles.push(...Object.values(newArticles)) 

          console.log(articles);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send();
  }
```

Problem has been solved!

Comment: What do the console logs output? An empty array for "articles"? What about "newArticles"?

Comment: if newArticles is an object, then you want to push the keys of an object in an array or the values? you can't loop through object using for, use for-in or Object.entries.


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: What is the data type of newArticles?

Comment: @H. Figueiredo console.log(newObj) returns the entire object, which contains way more than just the articles.

newArticles returns an object which has the 5 articles as objects inside it. 

articles returns an empty array.

Comment: @Apurvajain The data type is an object. newArticles is an object which contains 5 objects, the articles which I want to push to the array.

Comment: @AZ_

newArticles is indeed an object, but it has the 5 objects which I want to push to the global array inside of it. I have tried using the keys method, but that way it only sent the names of the 5 objects as strings, not the entire objects (but it is possible I didn't do it correctly).

Comment: Objects are in key value pair its not 'name'.
you simply can do articles = [...articles, ...Object.values(newArticles )]
assumed newArticles don't have anything else.

Comment: @AZ_ This seems to be the right way, but right now it seems like it creates a new array with the objects in it WITHIN the "articles" array. **EDIT:** I think the problem lies with the fact that I currently push all the objects at the same time, but I want to push them each individually using some sort of loop.

Comment: add your newArticles in the question.

Comment: @AZ_ Hope I can clarify what I mean. I currently use `articles.push(Object.values(newArticles));` instead of the for loop I have in the original question. The problem that I now encounter is that the objects within newArticles (which is also an object) get pushed as an array. So I end up with an array within an array. What I want to achieve is that every individual object within newArticles gets pushed to the articles array WITHOUT creating a new array.

Comment: I think AZ is correct, you need to use the for(value in newArticles). If this is not working, can you update the question with the code you're currently using?

Comment: use spread operator, this will solve your problem
articles.push(...Object.values(newArticles))

Comment: @H.Figueiredo I've updated the post in the hopes of clarifying the question I remain with.

Comment: @AZ_ Thanks, that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the issue simply by using [spread operator][1] ...

```
articles.push(...Object.values(newArticles));


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
```